# read from file in android using assets

Tags: java, android, file, android-activity, android-assets

I am trying to read file from assets in android. I want every button to print a paragraph, for example the first button prints the first paragraph and the second button print the second paragraph. 
I tried with the code below but its not working.

I get this error message:

```
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.hajjapp.AfterHajj } 
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622) 
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417) 
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370) –
```

Can anyone tell me where the problem is?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

  import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;

 public class BeforeHajj extends ActionBarActivity {
  Button whatHajj;
  TextView text;
  Button hajjTime;
  String before;
  String [] s;
  String timeHajj="";
  @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_before_hajj);

    whatHajj = (Button)findViewById(R.id.whatisHajj);
    hajjTime = (Button)findViewById(R.id.hajjTime);
    text =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);


    whatHajj.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            try
        {


            AssetManager assetmanager=getAssets();
            InputStream input=assetmanager.open("beforehaj.txt");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String st="";
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((st=br.readLine())!=null)
            {

                sb.append(st);


                before+=sb.toString();
                s=before.split("*");
            }
            text.setText(before);
        }
        catch(IOException ep) {
            text.append(ep.toString());
            }

        }
    });




    hajjTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View view) {
    // custom dialog

   try
        {


            AssetManager assetmanager=getAssets();
            InputStream input=assetmanager.open("beforehaj.txt");
            BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

            String st="";
            StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
            while((st=br.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(st);
                before+=sb.toString();
                s=before.split("*");
            }
        }
            catch(IOException ep) {
                text.append(ep.toString());
            }
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(BeforeHajj.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.guide_dialog);
        dialog.setTitle("Hajj Time");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_text);
        text.append(s[0]);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dolheja);
        Button dialogButton = (Button)  dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog

        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
            });

            dialog.show();
          }
        });
  }







 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.before_hajj, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Comment: Please explain what "but its NOT working" means. For example, is your program crashing? If yes, what is the Java stack trace associated with the crash?

Comment: yes it stop the application

Comment: 03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.example.hajjapp.AfterHajj }
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1622)
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1417)
03-03 18:40:17.800: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3370)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use new line character to split the paragraphs. All paragraphs start with a new line, so use

```
before.split("\\\n");
```

This shall do the job for you.

Comment: okay thank you its worked but i still have this error with second button which has the dialog   03-03 19:55:09.601: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 19:55:09.601: E/AndroidRuntime(1002): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1
03-03 19:55:09.601: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):  at com.example.hajjapp.BeforeHajj$2.onClick(BeforeHajj.java:103)
03-03 19:55:09.601: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
03-03 19:55:09.601: E/AndroidRuntime(1002):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)

Comment: First let me understand, do you want to dynamically create buttons in UI, based on the number of paragrahs in the file you are reading? Or two buttons are fixed?

Comment: i already created them they are 6 buttons every button will read a paragraph

Comment: According to your code, you are using a global string 'before' to store the string on first button click. Which has the modified string, as you have used before+=sb.toString(); then later in second button click you are splitting the before string. I believe you should clear the before string when you are on second button, and assign the next index after splitting the original value to the setText.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere, you are trying to start an activity that is supposed to be implemented in the Java class `com.example.hajjapp.AfterHajj`. The error message is telling you that there is no `<activity>` element in the manifest for this class. Also note that the code you pasted into your question is from a Java class named `BeforeHajj`.

Comment: 03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 1:
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144): *
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):  ^
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:407)
03-03 18:48:06.150: E/AndroidRuntime(1144):  at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:390)

Comment: @balloontofly: That is probably from `s=before.split("*");`, as `*` is not a valid regular expression in Java.

Comment: then what i can use instead of the * ?

Comment: @balloontofly: I am sorry, but I cannot understand that question. A search for `java regular expressions` on a major search engine turns up many pages of information that may help you in creating a valid regular expression, to go along with [the existing documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html). If you are literally trying to split on an asterisk character (`*`), I think `\\*` will be the correct regular syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use escape symbols to make the '*' be recognized by `split`, e.g. `s.split("\\*");`

Comment: ya i fixed this thanks. but  my big problem is with split since i have a file with many paragraph & i want different buttons to view only one paragraph of the same file

Comment: and should i put between the paragraphs the same symbol ?